# Why is the minimal value greater than zero?

Tags: javascript, numbers, min, zero

I was just testing numbers in JavaScript when I noticed something weird occurring.

Why is `Number.MIN_VALUE` greater than `0`? I expected it to be a very small negative value.

```js
console.log(Number.MIN_VALUE > 0);
```

Is there some mathematics behind it, or is it a JavaScript precision error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `Number.MIN_VALUE` is equal to `5e-324`. This can be shown below.

```js
console.log(Number.MIN_VALUE);
```

As you can see, the value is `5e-324`.

---

This is the smallest positive number that can be shown within float precision (float precision is relating to the `0.1 + 0.2` bug).

This is as close as you can get to `0`.

---

The technical smallest value is `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`.

```js
console.log(Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY);
```

However, this isn't really *"numerical"*, as the value is `-Infinity`, which can't be represented with a clear number.

Answer (score 0):

Number.MIN_VALUE: The smallest positive representable number—that is, the positive number closest to zero (without actually being zero).

When you run `console.log(Number.MIN_VALUE);`, you'll see the output as `5e-324`.

And I might add, what you expect might be `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` or `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`

See [Number | Javascript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)